# Use boostrap footer class in navbar shiny layout

Tags: r, shiny

I want to include footer to my `navbarPage` shiny layout. There exist footer argument in the main function:
https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.5/navbarPage.html

but I would like to use boostrap classes for footer:
https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/navigation/footer/

So, I would like to know, how to include, for example this HTML code to my shiny App:

```
<footer class="page-footer font-small blue">

  <!-- Copyright -->
  <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">© 2018 Copyright:
    <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/education/bootstrap/"> MDBootstrap.com</a>
  </div>
  <!-- Copyright -->

</footer>
<!-- Footer -->
```

I tried:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  navbarPage("MyApp", 
             theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
             tabPanel("Test"),
             footer = tagList(
               br(),
               div(p("test"), class="footer-copyright text-center py-3"),
               class = "page-footer font-small cyan darken-3"
             )

  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output,session) {

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

but it doesn't show nice footer, just plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the required links for *mdbootstrap* from [here](https://mdbootstrap.com/md-bootstrap-cdn/), use `tags$link` in `tags$head` to pass these links.
Then pass the *footer* using `tags$footer`. Finally, open the App in a browser to see the footer theme.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css"),
            tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"),
            tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.8.11/css/mdb.min.css")),
  navbarPage("MyApp", 
             theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
             tabPanel("Test")),
  tags$footer(HTML("
                    <!-- Footer -->
                           <footer class='page-footer font-large indigo'>
                           <!-- Copyright -->
                           <div class='footer-copyright text-center py-3'>© 2018 Copyright:
                           <a href='https://mdbootstrap.com/education/bootstrap/'> MDBootstrap.com</a>
                           </div>
                           <!-- Copyright -->

                           </footer>
                           <!-- Footer -->")))
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output,session) {}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Why the te color is not set to blue? The last part says it should be blue and in the link that shows bootstrap example, the footer is blue. Later I will use some other color, but not sure why this doesn't work? Also, if I use font-large instead of font-small, nothing happens. IT seems like it doesn't use `class='page-footer font-small blue'` part. Maybe the footer argument already use default class, and it is not overrided by the new class.

Comment: @Mislav sorry I didn't get it right the 1st time. please see my update.